# What is the data type "Unit is Adj" in Q#?

Tags: programming, q#

I came across it as the return type of operations in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.13835. It is also used in various places in the Q# documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unit is Adj` is not a data type per se, but rather a combination of two things:

1. Data type `Unit` that indicates that this operation does not have a return value.
2. Suffix `is Adj` that indicates that this operation implements a unitary transformation and has an adjoint specialization (either generated automatically or provided manually in the code, depending on the body of the operation). The operation can also say `is Ctl` to indicate that it has a controlled specialization, or `is Adj+Ctl` to indicate that it has both.

These suffixes can only occur for operations that return `Unit` type, so they can look indeed as a fixed code fragment together.

You can find more info about operation specializations in Q# in the [documentation on operations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/language/typesystem/operationsandfunctions#operation-characteristics).